# Swift scroll to top not working after load more

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview which has load more. I'd like to add scroll to top function when user press tabbar item twice like twitter, instagram.

This is my code when user tap twice to tab bar item.

```
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
      if previousController == viewController {
        if let navVC = viewController as? UINavigationController, let vc = navVC.viewControllers.first as? AssistantMainViewController {
            if vc.isViewLoaded && (vc.view.window != nil) {
                // viewController is visible
                vc.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -173), animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
    previousController = viewController
}
```

It works fine when tableview first load. The problem is when I load more cell to my tableview and scroll to top, tableview not scrolls to top it stuck in middle of somewhere. Other weird thing is if I scroll manually to top after load more, tab bar item scroll tableview properly until load more cells.

In load more action basicly app get more content from server and add them to array and call tableview.reloadData()

```
adviceDataSource.loadMoreContent(beforeDay: beforeDate, success: {feedCount in
        if feedCount == 0 {
            self.didGetLastPage = true
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.tableView.layoutSubviews()
        self.isRunningRequest = false
    }, error: { (errorString, statusCode) in
        self.isRunningRequest = false

    }) { (MoyaError) in
        self.isRunningRequest = false
    }
```

Probably the problem is when I load more cell tableview doesn't know its new content size.By the way when tap status bar tableview scroll to top perfectly. If you know the func that called when user tap status bar, it would be perfect for me.

I've been working and searching on it 2 days, any help?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try using `tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)`?

Comment: I've tried but my tableview cells not start to top of the screen so I need to do with content offset but if there is no solution I have to do with scrollToRow. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `scrollRectToVisible(_:animated:)` ?

Comment: It's not working aswell  @OmarChaabouni

Answer (score 0):

call UITabBarControllerDelegate in your viewcontroller tableView class.

in viewdidload Method call 
self.tabBarController?.delegate = self

implement tab bar didselect in your viewcontroller class

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
    if tabBarIndex == 0 {
        self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace tableView.layoutSubviews() with tableView.layoutIfNeeded(), it layout the tableview immediately.

And use the tabbarcontrollerdelegate:
The viewcontroller(which owns the tableview) will listen to it. and use this method

self.primaryTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition, animated: Bool)